# How To Invoke a Method While Turn off the Monitor as well as Turn on the Monitor by pressing button on monitor

Tags: c#, wpf

I want To Invoke the Following Method while Turn off the Monitor

```
    Stopwatch sw =new Stopwatch();        
    sw.Stop();
```

also i want to invoke the following Method while Turn on the Monitor

```
    sw.Start();
```

Is there any possible way to do this in c#?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# How to get the events when the screen/display goes to power OFF or ON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208595/c-sharp-how-to-get-the-events-when-the-screen-display-goes-to-power-off-or-on)

Comment: In this link i dint get how to invoke methods while turnoff and turn on using monitor button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning off monitor is completely different from operating system function. In a windows system it  shows just the output given by the System. It does not take any input to the system. So you cannot add any functionality to your program using the power button of the monitor. If the monitor turns off automatically by the power management system you can trigger events but not by pressing power button of monitor.