# Events fired when the display power is switched On/Off

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, screen

I search for an event or if doesn't exist, a method to know if the screen off (Power Options – Control Panel - Turn off the display setting).

None of these solutions work for me.
So either I was wrong somewhere, or it's just not suitable.

[How to get the events when the screen/display goes to power OFF or ON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208595/c-sharp-how-to-get-the-events-when-the-screen-display-goes-to-power-off-or-on)

I expect some track or solution.
The problem is that I don't know what I'm doing, if you could help me a little more it would be cool.

I made this, but it doesn't work:

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    public static Guid GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON = new Guid(0x02731015, 0x4510, 0x4526, 0x99, 0xE6, 0xE5, 0xA1, 0x7E, 0xBD, 0x1A, 0xEA);
    public const int DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE = 0x00000000;
    public const int WM_POWERBROADCAST = 0x0218;
    public const int PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE = 0x8013;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
    public struct POWERBROADCAST_SETTING
    {
        public Guid PowerSetting;
        public uint DataLength;
        public byte Data;
    }

    [DllImport(@"User32", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "RegisterPowerSettingNotification", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern IntPtr RegisterPowerSettingNotification(IntPtr hRecipient, ref Guid PowerSettingGuid, Int32 Flags);

    [DllImport(@"User32", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "UnregisterPowerSettingNotification", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool UnregisterPowerSettingNotification(IntPtr handle);
}

private void WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("EVENT", "DEBUG");
}

public form1()
{
    NativeMethods.RegisterPowerSettingNotification(this.Handle, ref NativeMethods.GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON, NativeMethods.DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The declarations are mostly correct, you just need to handle the messages when you're notified.

Override [OnHandleCreated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.onhandlecreated), to be sure that the Window handle is valid when you pass it to the function.
Override [WndProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc), to receive and process the [`WM_POWERBROADCAST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/wm-powerbroadcast) event.
Note that the Guid used in Windows 8+ is different from the one used in Window 7.
Not much, in Windows 8+ is also available a [`POWERBROADCAST_SETTING.Data`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-powerbroadcast_setting) value of **`0x02`**, including the **`Monitor Dimmed`** status; anyway, it's recommended that you use this Guid instead.
You can check the [OSVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.osversion) before calling [RegisterPowerSettingNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerpowersettingnotification).
This function returns a handle (`IntPtr`), which is used to call [UnregisterPowerSettingNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-unregisterpowersettingnotification) after.

The first notification is sent as soon as your application begins to process the messages (you should receive a message informing you that the Monitor is On :).
Note that these events are notified when the System turns On/Off or dims the Display power, not if you switch the Monitor's Power button On/Off.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private IntPtr unRegPowerNotify = IntPtr.Zero;

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        var settingGuid = new NativeMethods.PowerSettingGuid();
        Guid powerGuid = IsWindows8Plus()
                       ? settingGuid.ConsoleDisplayState 
                       : settingGuid.MonitorPowerGuid;

        unRegPowerNotify = NativeMethods.RegisterPowerSettingNotification(
            this.Handle, powerGuid, NativeMethods.DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
    }

    private bool IsWindows8Plus()
    {
        var version = Environment.OSVersion.Version;
        if (version.Major > 6) return true; // Windows 10+
        if (version.Major == 6 && version.Minor > 1) return true; // Windows 8+
        return false;  // Windows 7 or less
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg) {
            case NativeMethods.WM_POWERBROADCAST:
                if (m.WParam == (IntPtr)NativeMethods.PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE)
                {
                    var settings = (NativeMethods.POWERBROADCAST_SETTING)m.GetLParam(
                        typeof(NativeMethods.POWERBROADCAST_SETTING));
                    switch (settings.Data) {
                        case 0:
                            Console.WriteLine("Monitor Power Off");
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            Console.WriteLine("Monitor Power On");
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Console.WriteLine("Monitor Dimmed");
                            break;
                    }
                }
                m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
                break;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        NativeMethods.UnregisterPowerSettingNotification(unRegPowerNotify);
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
    }
}
```

**NativeMethods declarations**:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class NativeMethods
{
    internal const uint DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE = 0x0;
    internal const uint DEVICE_NOTIFY_SERVICE_HANDLE = 0x1;
    internal const int WM_POWERBROADCAST = 0x0218;
    internal const int PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE = 0x8013;

    [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr RegisterPowerSettingNotification(IntPtr hWnd, [In] Guid PowerSettingGuid, uint Flags);

    [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool UnregisterPowerSettingNotification(IntPtr hWnd);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
    internal struct POWERBROADCAST_SETTING
    {
        public Guid PowerSetting;
        public uint DataLength;
        public byte Data;
    }

    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/power-setting-guids
    public class PowerSettingGuid
    {
        // 0=Powered by AC, 1=Powered by Battery, 2=Powered by short-term source (UPC)
        public Guid AcdcPowerSource { get; } = new Guid("5d3e9a59-e9D5-4b00-a6bd-ff34ff516548");
        // POWERBROADCAST_SETTING.Data = 1-100
        public Guid BatteryPercentageRemaining { get; } = new Guid("a7ad8041-b45a-4cae-87a3-eecbb468a9e1");
        // Windows 8+: 0=Monitor Off, 1=Monitor On, 2=Monitor Dimmed
        public Guid ConsoleDisplayState { get; } = new Guid("6fe69556-704a-47a0-8f24-c28d936fda47");
        // Windows 8+, Session 0 enabled: 0=User providing Input, 2=User Idle
        public Guid GlobalUserPresence { get; } = new Guid("786E8A1D-B427-4344-9207-09E70BDCBEA9");
        // 0=Monitor Off, 1=Monitor On.
        public Guid MonitorPowerGuid { get; } = new Guid("02731015-4510-4526-99e6-e5a17ebd1aea");
        // 0=Battery Saver Off, 1=Battery Saver On.
        public Guid PowerSavingStatus { get; } = new Guid("E00958C0-C213-4ACE-AC77-FECCED2EEEA5");

        // Windows 8+: 0=Off, 1=On, 2=Dimmed
        public Guid SessionDisplayStatus { get; } = new Guid("2B84C20E-AD23-4ddf-93DB-05FFBD7EFCA5");

        // Windows 8+, no Session 0: 0=User providing Input, 2=User Idle
        public Guid SessionUserPresence { get; } = new Guid("3C0F4548-C03F-4c4d-B9F2-237EDE686376");
        // 0=Exiting away mode 1=Entering away mode
        public Guid SystemAwaymode { get; } = new Guid("98a7f580-01f7-48aa-9c0f-44352c29e5C0");

        /* Windows 8+ */
        // POWERBROADCAST_SETTING.Data not used
        public Guid IdleBackgroundTask { get; } = new Guid(0x515C31D8, 0xF734, 0x163D, 0xA0, 0xFD, 0x11, 0xA0, 0x8C, 0x91, 0xE8, 0xF1);

        public Guid PowerSchemePersonality { get; } = new Guid(0x245D8541, 0x3943, 0x4422, 0xB0, 0x25, 0x13, 0xA7, 0x84, 0xF6, 0x79, 0xB7);

        // The Following 3 Guids are the POWERBROADCAST_SETTING.Data result of PowerSchemePersonality
        public Guid MinPowerSavings { get; } = new Guid("8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c");
        public Guid MaxPowerSavings { get; } = new Guid("a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a");
        public Guid TypicalPowerSavings { get; } = new Guid("381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e");
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much.
I'm analyzing the code, but I think that it's complicated to just get the screen power event ^^

Comment: It's standard procedure when you need to filter Windows messages. Of course, the NativeMethods class (often a partial class), is included in a Project linking a reusable class file. The Form's Handlers are often wired/unwired by a Model/Manager class. The same goes for the `m.Msg` of `WndProc`, which is handled elsewhere (another specialized class). So your Form will remain unchanged, in practice. If you do this kind of stuff often, you already have all these *manager* classes in place when the Project is created, so there's not much to add, except some code for new message type.

Comment: IIRC, there's another method to get the same notification, using WMI Events. Not sure if you'ld consider it less complicated, though. There's less code for sure, since no PInvoking is involved.

Comment: Yes I see.
I would look for WMI.

Answer (score 1):

You must call **RegisterPowerSettingNotification** first
and you will receive **WM_POWERBROADCAST** message